# Multiple conditions when searching one table

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want to search inside one table for the rows that apply to the condition of (between date 1 and date 2 and with the client id of "X" and with category "Y" and publication name "Z").

Problem is the code i wrote needs all fields to be existing and i want to give ability for users to search with one condition or two.

CAN ANY ONE HELP .....

```
$DBObject->QueryText="SELECT * from printed WHERE 
    printed_cat_id=".$cat2["printed_cat_id"]." 
    and clientid=".$_SESSION["clientid"]." 
    and publication_id=".$_GET["pub"]." 
    and photo_tag like ".$tag." 
    and date BETWEEN '".$_GET["date1"]."' AND '".$_GET["date2"]."'";
```

Comment: use `or` Than, i think

Comment: can you give sample table values and what are you expecting the output?

Comment: It is a table contains 6 columns:

Answer (score 0):

In your query you can just test if your field is empty or not.

Example for field "pub":

```
and (".$_GET["pub"]." is null || publication_id=".$_GET["pub"]." )
```

Then if pub is null, it won't be taken into consideration.
You can also test '' if you want.

Comment: Dear William thanks for your help but your answer is generating mysql error , i am new user of php and mysql ,so please tell me exactly a full sample query to insert it, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to make some of the conditions optional, you could build the query programatically based on the `GET` parameters given, ie:

```
$query = "SELECT * from printed WHERE
    printed_cat_id=".$cat2["printed_cat_id"]." 
    clientid=".$_SESSION["clientid"];

if(isset($_GET["pub"]))
{
    $query .= " and publication_id=".$_GET["pub"];
}

if(isset($tag))
{
    $query .= " and photo_tag=".$tag;
}
if(isset($_GET['date1']) && isset($_GET['date2']) )
{
    $query .= " and date BETWEEN '".$_GET["date1"]."' AND '".$_GET["date2"]."'";
}

$DBObject->QueryText=$query;
```

this way only parameters which are posted will be included and checked against in the `mysql` `query`

On the other hand (not clear in your question) if you only want at least one of the conditions to be true, you could use `OR` instead of `AND` inside your query for those parts

Comment: Hi Kypros your answer is not working however it seems to be logical correct, but i am a new developer i just added these 2 lines to continue:

Comment: $printed= $DBObject->DBConnect();
while( ($printedrow=mysql_fetch_array($printed))){

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it produce wrong results or an error? If wrong results please `echo $query` and gives us the output, along with info what is expected and what you get.